# ffmpeg subtitle font size too big

Tags: ffmpeg

After making subtitles in Aegisub, I save it as .ass file, with font size set from style manager,
I used this command

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -b:v 1M -vf subtitles=subtitle.ass out.mp4
```

But the output file has the font a few sizes too big, larger than the original size I set in Aegisub.

Did I do something wrong?

This was the intended size:

[image]

And this is the output size:

[image]

Comment: You say you saved it as .ass but your filter is loading a srt file.

Comment: oh no sorry, I forgot to edit it, I really did put in the ass file, gonna edit it now

Comment: Provide your ass file. What player are you using?

Comment: I often use PotPlayer, here's the ass file
[ass file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AqLe_gGBphT8ih7ArltGLXg3r4la6-bT)

Comment: Fontsize in the file is set as 120, 80, 70, and 20. The first 3 sizes are of course huge.